# How to return a TRUE/FALSE value based on whether a value exists in any given columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
Fruits1     Fruits2   Fruits3       Apple      Banana       Lemon
N/A         N/A       Apple         N/A        N/A          N/A
Apple       Lemon     N/A           N/A        N/A          N/A
N/A         Banana    Apple         N/A        N/A          N/A
```

I want to search on the first three columns, and then use the last three column names to return a TRUE/FALSE value when that column name appears in any row of the first three columns, like that:

```
Fruits1     Fruits2   Fruits3      Apple       Banana       Lemon
N/A         N/A       Apple        TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
Apple       Lemon     N/A          TRUE        FALSE        TRUE
N/A         Banana    Apple        TRUE        TRUE         FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

In `base` r, you can use `apply`, `is.element`, and `t` as follows:

```
df1[4:6] <- t(apply(df1[1:3], 1, is.element, el = names(df1[4:6])))

#   Fruits1 Fruits2 Fruits3 Apple Banana Lemon
# 1     N/A     N/A   Apple  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
# 2   Apple   Lemon     N/A  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
# 3     N/A  Banana   Apple  TRUE   TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Also `df1[4:6] <- t(apply(df1[1:3], 1, function(x) names(df1[4:6]) %in% x))`

Answer (score 1):

With tidyverse using `gather` and `spread`

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  select(Fruits1:Fruits3)

df %>% 
  mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
  gather("key", "fruit", -i) %>% 
  filter(fruit != "N/A") %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  mutate(true = T) %>% 
  spread("fruit", "true", fill = F) %>% 
  select(-i) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

this solution will work even if you add more fruit

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` we can `unlist` the first 3 columns, create a `table` with the `rep`licated row index, check if the count is greater than 0 and assign it back to the columns 4 to 6.

```
df1[4:6] <- table(seq_len(nrow(df1))[row(df1[1:3])], unlist(df1[1:3]))[,1:3] > 0
df1
#  Fruits1 Fruits2 Fruits3 Apple Banana Lemon
#1     N/A     N/A   Apple  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#2   Apple   Lemon     N/A  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
#3     N/A  Banana   Apple  TRUE   TRUE FALSE
```

NOTE: The missing values `NA` where shown as character string (`"N/A"`)

NOTE2: This is vectorized instead of looping over each row

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fruits1 = c("N/A", "Apple", "N/A"), Fruits2 = c("N/A", 
"Lemon", "Banana"), Fruits3 = c("Apple", "N/A", "Apple"), Apple = c("N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A"), Banana = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), Lemon = c("N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```